# Can I define record helper for TBytes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I am using Delphi XE4.  I try to define some helper function for TBytes:

```
TBytesHelper = record helper for TBytes
public
  function GetLength: integer;
end;

function TBytesHelper.GetLength: integer;
begin
  Result := System.Length(Self);
end;
```

When I try to consume the new helper function:

```
var B: TBytes;
    i: integer;
begin
  B := TBytes.Create(1,2,3);
  i := B.GetLength;

  if i <> Length(B) then
    raise Exception.Create('Incorrect result');
end;
```

I except the result for `i` is `3` but it doesn't.  I refer to TStringHelper define in SysUtils.pas that has similar construct.

Is there anything I miss?

Comment: That code won't even compile in XE3. Fails at `B.GetLength` with `[dcc32 Error]: E2018 Record, object or class type required`. What is `TBytes` in XE4. Is it still `TArray<Byte>`? I did not think helpers could be used with generic types.

Comment: Yes. It won't compile in `XE3`.  That's why I am using `XE4` as stated in my question.

Comment: I was offering some extra information in case it proved helpful. I guess you took my comment the wrong way. Never mind. As an aside, you should be tagging the question delphi-xe4 as well as using the general dephhi tag. What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Thanks. I tag the question as `delphi-xe4` now.

Comment: I'm still curious to know what debugging you have done. What value does `i` have? Where does that value come from? What is `Self` in your helper function. My feeling is that the code is not meant to compile at all because record helpers do not work with generics.

Comment: You should declare `TMyByteArray = array of byte;` and then `TBytesHelper = record helper for TMyByteArray`.

Comment: The value of `i` is unexpected.  Once I enter the GetLength() method, the `self` (i suppose it is the TBytes array) is a very large byte array instead of (1,2,3) as defined.

Comment: @LURD But then you cannot take advantage of type compatibility benefits that come from using `TBytes` which is an alias for `TArray<Byte>`. Your `TMyByteArray` is ghettoised.

Comment: LURD suggestion works but David Hefferman's comment is true also.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang Well, it won't be a different byte array. Your program only makes one. It's presumably a pointer to some other part of memory totally unrelated. For debugging, output to a console window `Pointer(Self)` from your helper method, and `Pointer(B)` from the calling code. They should be the same, but won't be.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, so is this consider a bug in Delphi compiler?

Comment: @ChauCheeYang Clearly it's a bug if `Self` in a helper method does not refer to the helper subject.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, my suggestion is a workaround for the limitations(bugs) in the compiler. Not clean as you say. I want all intrinsic functions/procedures implemented as class operators. I want class operators on record helpers. Add record helpers inheritance to the list as well. Then the language would be truly modular.

Comment: @LURD I'm with you apart from helper inheritance. I don't think we need helper inheritance as much as the ability to resolve methods in multiple helper scopes. Using generic dynamic arrays is critically important. Type compatibility is one issue, but the ability to use and return `TArray<T>` in generic types is essential.

Comment: I have filed a QC issue: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=116472

Answer (score 3):

This problem was discussed here:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=88409
In few words - you can define your own type and use it with record helper:

```
type
 TMyBytes = array of Byte;

 TBytesHelper = record helper for TMyBytes
   function GetLength: integer;
 end;
```

But it doesn't work with TBytes defined in Delphi. Support of helpers for generic types was added recently, so probably it is kind of limitations of current implementation.